# How to use STL in unix?

Tags: unix, stl

How to use STL(standard Temple library) in HP-Unix . How to compile and run the program with STL functions?

Answer (score 2):

If for some strange reason HP-UX's development tools don't have it then you can download the reference implementation [from SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).

Comment: Thanks for your info. But i dont find anything in SGI for unix

Comment: ... Did you even bother going to the link?

Comment: can you please tell me the exact link

Comment: It's in the answer. Try clicking.